# Leaving a Domain effects

Tags: domain

I have a server on a DOMAIN running special services on the user account
WHATEVERDOMAINIS\Admin. I want to remove it off the DOMAIN because the controller no longer exist. I am just worried if I do remove it and place it on local account 
"Administrator" the services that were installed from WHATEVERDOMAINIS\Admin will no longer work and the programs will be all unconfigured. Any insight?

Answer (score 4):

Switch that service account to run as a local user with equivalent permissions and then unkoin from the domain. If your AD DS domain is gone then it's just using cached credentials anyway and isn't getting any special rights via it's AD DS group membership.

Comment: when I check the service properties it already says "Local System Account".I assume its already ready to move to local account as is?